# "[__NSArrayI data]: unrecognized selector" when accessing FlutterStandardTypedData from dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a `Uint8List` in Flutter, put it in a JSON string and pass that string to the native code. 
Here is my **Flutter code**:

```
final jsonObj = {
  "dataBuffer": dataBuffer, // dataBuffer is of type Uint8List
};

String encodedJson = json.encode(jsonObj);

await _channel.invokeMethod('testMethod', <String, dynamic>{
  'jsonObj': encodedJson,
});
```

Here is the native **iOS code** where I try to get the `Uint8List` out of the JSON string as a `FlutterStandardTypedData`:

```
- (void)handleMethodCall:(FlutterMethodCall*)call result:(FlutterResult)result {
  if ([@"testMethod" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
    NSString* jsonString = (NSString*)call.arguments[@"jsonObj"];
    NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *responseObj = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                 options:0
                                 error:&error];

    if(! error) {
        FlutterStandardTypedData *dataBufferJson = [responseObj objectForKey:@"dataBuffer"];
        NSData *bufferData = [dataBufferJson data]; *** // Here is where the exception is thrown ***
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to get the `data` property of the `FlutterStandardTypedData` I get the following exception:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI data]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff8f21ad000'

I can't understand the reason why I get this error, but I think it is dealing with the fact that the `Uint8List` has been put in a JSON, or with the fact that I'm trying to get the `FlutterStandardTypedData` from a dictionary in the wrong way. Anyway I can't find the solution.

I also tried to pass the `Uint8List` from Flutter to native in another way: in Dart I passed the `Uint8List` directly to the native code (without encapsulating it in a JSON string). In this way I can get the `FlutterStandardTypedData` object successfully. Here is the code of the other example.

**Dart code:**

```
await _channel.invokeMethod('testMethod',
  dataBuffer, // example Uint8List
);
```

**iOS code:**

```
- (void)handleMethodCall:(FlutterMethodCall*)call result:(FlutterResult)result {
  if ([@"testMethod" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
    FlutterStandardTypedData* dataBuffer = (FlutterStandardTypedData*)call.arguments[@"dataBuffer"];
  }
}
```

However I need to pass the `Uint8List` though a JSON string.

How can I pass a `Uint8List` from Flutter to iOS native encapsulating it in a JSON string?

Comment: What's the reason you want to wrap the bytes in JSON? As you show, the correct way to do it is to pass it directly.

Comment: In my application I call a native method passing in an object that stores the ‘‘‘Uint8List‘‘‘ and other properties. In order to pass this object to the native code I must convert it to a JSON string.

Comment: There isn't really a JSON representation of a byte array. It handles numbers, strings, booleans, etc. How does your API want the byte array represented in JSON?

Comment: I don't know, but in the Android native code I can successfully convert the JSON string (containing the ```Uint8List```) to a Java Object using Gson. In Java I convert the ```Uint8List``` to a ```byte[]```.

Comment: If you are decoding the JSON at the native end back to its component parts, what's the point of the intermediate JSON form? Just pass a `Map<String, dynamic>` across the Dart-native boundary. Each member of the map could be a different (supported) type, for example string, boolean, integer, floating point, byte array, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that what you are trying to do is to pass multiple 'parameters' across the Dart-native boundary. Use a `Map<String, dynamic>` for this. For example:

```
await _channel.invokeMethod('testMethod', <String, dynamic>{
    'bytes': dataBuffer, // example Uint8List
    'someBool': true,
    'someInt': 123,
  }
);
```

At the native end you'll get a map or dictionary containing the key names as keys and the values as their native equivalents (for example `bool`->`Boolean` etc)

Comment: thanks for answering. I can't do this exactly, but I can try to pass another ```Map``` (containing ```dataBuffer```, this time not converted to string) as argument of the ```Map``` passed to ```invokeMethod```.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did what I said in my previous comment and it solved my problem. Instead of converting the JSON to string and passing it to ```invokeMethod``` as a ```Map```, and then in iOS I accessed it as a normal ```NSDictionary```.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C does not have any compile time type safety tools and leaves that responsibility to the developer. The exception here says that you've tried to use an array object as if it was a FlutterStandardTypedData object. But it appeared not to be the case at runtime.

I don't know how Dart serializes Uint8List into json but looking at the exception, it looks like it's something like "[3,5,7]". Deserializing this in Objective-C, you get an array of ints, not a FlutterStandardTypedData. The items in the array may be of type FlutterStandardTypedData.

Comment: Then, how can I get the ‘‘‘FlutterStandardTypedData‘‘‘ out of the JSON string? Should I extract ‘‘‘dataBuffer‘‘‘ as an array of ints and then create a ‘‘‘FlutterStandardTypedData‘‘‘ from that array?

Comment: I don't know Flutter and what FlutterStandardTypedData does but thinking on the Objective-C side, you need to deserialize the json into an array and every member of the array will be an int/float (or NSNumber). Just place a breakpoint in your code and check out the type of the value you have in the array.

Comment: I tried to extract the array from the dictionary as an ```NSArray```, convert it to an ```NSData``` object and then to a ```FlutterStandardTypedData``` object, but I can't access the content of the buffer, so I think that something has been ruined in the process.

Comment: Do not convert NSArray to NSData. Just access the members of the array like arr[0] and you'll find an int or an NSNumber there.

Comment: Thank you @Srdr , but I solved my problem with the answer of Richard Heap . Please see the comments under his answer.